# Why @InjectRepository() is needed if nestjs injects instance of the Repository class already in constructor?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have this `TaskRepository` class which extends `Repository` class.

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Task } from './task.entity';

@EntityRepository(Task)
export class TaskRepository extends Repository<Task> {}
```

I know this class is not needed as we can do the below.

```
@Controller('tasks')
export class TasksController {
    
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Task)
    private readonly taskRepository: Repository<Task>
  ) {}
}
```

But, this is why I am consfused.

```
@Controller('tasks')
export class TasksController {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(TaskRepository)
    private taskRepository: TasRepository,
  ) {}
}
```

Here, nestjs will resolve the depedency `TaskRepository` which already extends `Respository`
class and `Entity`  is already injected, so it knows for which entity repository is.

Why we need `@InjectRepository(TaskRepository)`here?

Comment: [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205800/understanding-inject-injectable-and-injectrepository-in-nest)

Comment: and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65941047/5290447)

Answer (score -2):

According to the convention your controller should never communicate with the repository directly. Instead, use a service for doing so.

The controller should only be used to direct your API'S to the right service. Service will communicate with repository and do the required requests and send back the response.

Your first statement

> I know this class is not needed as we can do the below.

is correct. You will need to create a customer repository when you have custom and complex database queries else you can use the provided repository itself.

While Importing repository in your controller is not a good practice but even if you do. You are just injecting an instance of your Repository to the controller.

Comment: That is not what he asked. You are answering something which he didn't asked!

Comment: Yes, my question was if I already have `private taskRepository: TasRepository,` in the constructor. Nestjs should inject an instance of the repository. Why we need to decorate it with `@InjectRepository(TaskRepository)`  as `TaskRespostory` already extends `Repository` and knows for which entity the repository is  `@EntityRepository(Task)`?

Comment: @confusedWarrior have you found the answer of this?